# AWS Lambda, how to properly instantiate AmazonHttpClient?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

The things which seems to be extremely easy in `Node.JS` lambda implementation:

```
var https = require("https");
```

doesn't work in Java lambda:

```
AmazonHttpClient httpClient = AmazonHttpClient.builder().build();
```

gives me an exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: client configuration cannot be
>   null at
>   com.amazonaws.util.ValidationUtils.assertNotNull(ValidationUtils.java:37)
>   at
>   com.amazonaws.http.settings.HttpClientSettings.(HttpClientSettings.java:44)
>   at
>   com.amazonaws.http.settings.HttpClientSettings.adapt(HttpClientSettings.java:52)
>   at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.(AmazonHttpClient.java:314) 
>   at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.(AmazonHttpClient.java:131) 
>   at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$Builder.build(AmazonHttpClient.java:396)

Why? How to properly configure it?

Comment: There are no lambdas in anything you've posted.

Comment: I mean that it doesn't work in lambda. What do you want from me to post?

Comment: well, the node code you posted has nothing to do with the java code.

Comment: My question is clear enough. You don't need to teach me how to post MCVE. I am not going to litter my question with useless class and method declaration.

Comment: are you comparing the (js code to the java code) in a lambda or are you comparing java code run outside of a lamba with java code run inside of a lambda?

Comment: Instead of giving me useless commentaries, you would better fix the tag, as @luk2302 did, it was simply a misprint. Or do you really think that I can not distinguish aws lambda from lambda? That's simply disrespectful.

Comment: @Asdfg I will not. Never.

Comment: Andrew, how about you say what you're trying to do? 

The nodejs snippet you posted is not related to the AmazonHttpClient class. The AmazonHttpClient is used for AWS as you can see here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/http/AmazonHttpClient.html#AmazonHttpClient-com.amazonaws.ClientConfiguration-

Comment: It's nothing to do with that and you're being incredibly defensive.

Comment: The fact is that instead of silently fix tag from "lambda" to "aws-lambda", you started teach me how to write MCVE, pointing on unrelated things.

Comment: @Andremoniy It's entirely your responsibility to make your question easy to understand. I didn't know what AWS Lamdba is. It doesn't even seem to have any bearing on your question. Even without the AWS Lambda / lambda confusion, it's not clear what you want us to tell you. The error message literally tells you exactly what's wrong.

Comment: I have to agree with what has been said already: the error message is entirely clear, the answer does fit and tells you what to do when looking at the docs. The community is not the problem but right now it is your attitude and the phrasing of your question. I have posted two comments asking for clarification, both without reaction. @Michael was absolutely correct in being confused about the term "lambda". He does not realize that in fact it can have an impact on the question and the code working without any code difference, but that is not his fault, the tag originally was incorrect.

Comment: First of all, I appreciate @luk2302 that you have properly change the tags. Thanks for that. But anyway, please, vote to delete this question. It became a b...t.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/http/AmazonHttpClient.Builder.html), the class returned by `AmazonHTTPClient.builder()` can have a ClientConfiguration object set on it. The error message would suggest that this is required.

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about.     `public static Builder builder() {
        return new Builder();
    }` doesn't accept anything, and there is not mentioning about in configuration.

Comment: You will however see that there is a public method called `clientConfiguration` which, according to the source code, sets the private `clientConfig` field. https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/aws-java-sdk-core/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/http/AmazonHttpClient.java#L370

Comment: @dataman is right though - you really should use a normal Java HTTP client to make requests